# Silverstripe - Different tabs and fields per page

Tags: silverstripe

In SilverStripe 3.1 is it possible to add different tabs and fields on the about page for example.

And then different tabs and fields on a services page for example.

About Page - Images Tab / Attachments Tab

Services Page - Images Tab / Attachments Tab / Staff Person Tab

The following code is an example. I have added the if statements around a snippet that does work. But it only seems to work for all pages by showing the same tabs on all pages.

I've been doing the video lessons on the SilverStripe website and I can see that you can create page types but I really need to know if you can achieve this without having to create extra page types.

```php
// I want this on the about page 

// if page=about {

class Page extends SiteTree {

    private static $has_one = array (
        'Photo' => 'image',
        'Brochure' => 'file',
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Images', $photo = UploadField::create('Photo'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Attachments', $brochure = UploadField::create('Brochure'));

        return $fields;
    }

}

// I want this on the services page 

// } elseif page=services {

class Page extends SiteTree {

    private static $has_one = array (
        'Photo' => 'image',
        'Brochure' => 'file',
        'Staff Person' => 'image',
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Images', $photo = UploadField::create('Photo'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Attachments', $brochure = UploadField::create('Brochure'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Staff', $staff = UploadField::create('Staff'));
        return $fields;
    }

}

// }

class Page_Controller extends ContentController {

    private static $allowed_actions = array();

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use individual page types for what you want to do.

However, if you only want to use one page type you can use an if statement in your `getCMSFields` function to display different fields.

In this example code I check the `URLSegment`, although you could check something else like `Title`.

```php
class Page extends SiteTree {

    private static $has_one = array (        
        'Photo' => 'image',   
        'Brochure' => 'file', 
        'Staff Person' => 'image', 
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {        
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        if ($this->URLSegment == 'about' || $this->URLSegment == 'services') {
            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Images', $photo = UploadField::create('Photo'));
            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Attachments', $brochure = UploadField::create('Brochure'));     
        }
        if ($this->URLSegment == 'services') {
            $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Staff', $staff = UploadField::create('Staff'));
        }

        return $fields;         
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, please use different page types. If you accidently change the $URLSegment you cannot access the fields any more.
Different page types also have the big advantage that you can add a seperate layout template for them easily.

Comment: @3dgoo Thankyou, that worked nicley. I do understand how page types are much more stable. I was just curious if it could be done mainly for the home page actually. I wanted an easy way for a client to add several blocks of home page content via the tabs and this looks to be a good solution for now.